# Default cURL option values

Tags: php, curl, default

I was refactoring my cURL class today and thought about looking at default values of cURL FLAGS.
Could anyone tell me where I might find or how could I output them?

**PS:** If it's possible at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have been researching the same problem today and came across this (rather old) post. Since it shows up pretty much at the top of Google, I thought this is the place to conclude my research.

In short: It's not possible.

It seems like most cURL options do not even have any default values. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308915/php-default-curl-timeout-value), [timeouts](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2004-04/0027.html). [Or the user agent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102090). But many others do have defaults, as the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) states. I could not find any list of default values - neither for PHP's cURL extension, nor for cURL in general. Only individual defaults that are mentioned within said PHP manual or within the [cURL API doc](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html). However, I doubt that every single default is mentioned within those pages.

Unfortunately, finding them out programmatically is not possible, either. The idea would be to find out all options values before setting the first one. But [there is no `curl_getopt()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356075/how-to-get-an-option-previously-set-with-curl-setopt). Not even in cURL itself. All solutions that emulate `curl_getopt()` can only retrieve those options that have been set manually.

After a (very) short glance at the cURL source code (the original C lib) I also suspect that sometimes there are no real defaults, but if an option is not set, some logic goes into figuring out which value to use. In that case, default values would not even be well-defined.

Lastly, chances are that PHP's cURL extension employs some different defaults than cURL itself.

So unless some cURL developer sheds some light on this - or at least someone who has the time and skill to really dive into the code - we are pretty much stuck on this.

Answer (score 4):

While the PHP Docs for [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) enumerate the list of available options, it doesn't* show the defaults that PHP sets for every connection (default, until you overwrite them of course).

You can view these default options PHP sets for curl in the [ext/curl/interface.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/ext/curl/interface.c#L1928-L1958) file, in a call to `_php_curl_set_default_options(php_curl *ch)`.

At the current time, the default options + values are:

```
// "value" options
CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS              => 1
CURLOPT_VERBOSE                 => 0
CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT       => 120
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS               => 20

// callback functions
CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION           => curl_write
CURLOPT_READFUNCTION            => curl_read
CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION          => curl_write_header

// file/stream references
CURLOPT_INFILE                  => (void *)ch
CURLOPT_FILE                    => (void *)ch
CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER             => (void *)ch
CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER             => ch->err.str

// If ZTS (Zend Thread Safety) *is* enabled
CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL                => 1

// If ZTS (Zend Thread Safety) *is not* enabled
CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE    => 1

// OpenSSL CA File (`cainfo` = either in openssl.cafile, curl.cainfo or it doesn't exist)
// note: if the file doesn't exist, this option isn't set
CURLOPT_CAINFO                  => cainfo
```

* Note: The php doc *does* mention that it sets the default for `CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS`:

> PHP automatically sets this option to **TRUE**, this should only be changed for debugging purposes.

If you're curious about general default behavior of curl, you can view the individual options in the documentation for [`curl_easy_setopt()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) and [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt). The former gives a very detailed description of each, the latter a general summary. Both list the default behavior of curl without the option(s) set.

Comment: I wonder whether `CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY` is enabled by default as in curl

Answer (score 1):

This will display the "CURL*" constant names and their values:

```
foreach (get_defined_constants() as $name => $val) {
    if (strpos($name, 'CURL') === 0) {
        echo $name . ' => ' . $val . "\n";
    }
}
```

For just the curl option values, change 'CURL' to 'CURLOPT_', of course.

(If you're thinking of using the integer values instead of the constant names in your script, you shouldn't.)

Comment: +1 for the code. also, for reference to curl option flags check this - http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Comment: @bhu1st - +1 for your comment. It should be kept in mind, though, that not all the options described there are in the PHP implementation.

Comment: Ok. Now that's a bit strange. How is it possible `CURLOPT_HEADER => 42`? Shouldn't the value be 1 or 0 (true/false)?

Comment: @Eugene - The CURLOPT_* values are used under the hood in bitwise operations, not as true/false values. True and false are used only in the parameters to the curl_setopt() and curl_setopt_array() "convenience" functions.

Comment: @Eugene - I realize now that I haven't really answered your question. My code doesn't tell you whether a given option is on or off, only what the value of the constant is. Back to the proverbial drawing board.

Comment: Yes, I thought you were on the right track, but no, these constant values are kind of an internal ID for that particular setting, not the actual default value of the setting.  I think the answer by @m.buettner is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

Code to get the `CURLOPT` configuration options you will want to edit:

```
foreach (get_defined_constants() as $key => $val) {
    if (strpos($key, 'CURLOPT_') === 0) {
        echo $key . ' => ' . $val . "\n";
    }
}
```

Following are the default PHP CURL settings on my installation of PHP 5.6.30 on CentOS 7:

- `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER` 58
- `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` 19914
- `CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE` 98
- `CURLOPT_CAINFO` 10065
- `CURLOPT_CAPATH` 10097
- `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` 78
- `CURLOPT_COOKIE` 10022
- `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` 10031
- `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` 10082
- `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` 96
- `CURLOPT_CRLF` 27
- `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` 10036
- `CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT` 92
- `CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE` 91
- `CURLOPT_EGDSOCKET` 10077
- `CURLOPT_ENCODING` 10102
- `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` 45
- `CURLOPT_FILE` 10001
- `CURLOPT_FILETIME` 69
- `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` 52
- `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` 75
- `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT` 74
- `CURLOPT_FTPAPPEND` 50
- `CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY` 48
- `CURLOPT_FTPPORT` 10017
- `CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT` 106
- `CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV` 85
- `CURLOPT_HEADER` 42
- `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` 20079
- `CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES` 10104
- `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` 80
- `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` 10023
- `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` 61
- `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` 84
- `CURLOPT_INFILE` 10009
- `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE` 14
- `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` 10062
- `CURLOPT_KRB4LEVEL` 10063
- `CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT` 19
- `CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME` 20
- `CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS` 71
- `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` 68
- `CURLOPT_NETRC` 51
- `CURLOPT_NOBODY` 44
- `CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS` 43
- `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` 99
- `CURLOPT_PORT` 3
- `CURLOPT_POST` 47
- `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` 10015
- `CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE` 10039
- `CURLOPT_PREQUOTE` 10093
- `CURLOPT_PRIVATE` 10103
- `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` 20056
- `CURLOPT_PROXY` 10004
- `CURLOPT_PROXYPORT` 59
- `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE` 101
- `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD` 10006
- `CURLOPT_PUT` 54
- `CURLOPT_QUOTE` 10028
- `CURLOPT_RANDOM_FILE` 10076
- `CURLOPT_RANGE` 10007
- `CURLOPT_READDATA` 10009
- `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` 20012
- `CURLOPT_REFERER` 10016
- `CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM` 21
- `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` 19913
- `CURLOPT_SHARE` 10100
- `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` 10025
- `CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD` 10026
- `CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE` 10086
- `CURLOPT_SSLENGINE` 10089
- `CURLOPT_SSLENGINE_DEFAULT` 90
- `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` 10087
- `CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD` 10026
- `CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE` 10088
- `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` 32
- `CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST` 10083
- `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` 81
- `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` 64
- `CURLOPT_STDERR` 10037
- `CURLOPT_TELNETOPTIONS` 10070
- `CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION` 33
- `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` 13
- `CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE` 34
- `CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT` 53
- `CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH` 105
- `CURLOPT_UPLOAD` 46
- `CURLOPT_URL` 10002
- `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` 10018
- `CURLOPT_USERPWD` 10005
- `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` 41
- `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` 20011
- `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER` 10029
- `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` 107
- `CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS` 110
- `CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH` 111
- `CURLOPT_FTP_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT` 112
- `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` 113
- `CURLOPT_MAXFILESIZE` 114
- `CURLOPT_FTP_SSL` 119
- `CURLOPT_NETRC_FILE` 10118
- `CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH` 129
- `CURLOPT_FTP_ACCOUNT` 10134
- `CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY` 121
- `CURLOPT_COOKIELIST` 10135
- `CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH` 136
- `CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP` 137
- `CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD` 138
- `CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY` 141
- `CURLOPT_LOCALPORT` 139
- `CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE` 140
- `CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER` 10147
- `CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE` 30146
- `CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE` 30145
- `CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE` 150
- `CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC` 154
- `CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES` 151
- `CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE` 10153
- `CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE` 10152
- `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` 156
- `CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING` 158
- `CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING` 157
- `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` 155
- `CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL` 10063
- `CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS` 160
- `CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS` 159
- `CURLOPT_APPEND` 50
- `CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY` 48
- `CURLOPT_USE_SSL` 119
- `CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5` 10162
- `CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE` 166
- `CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE` 171
- `CURLOPT_CRLFILE` 10169
- `CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT` 10170
- `CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD` 10026
- `CURLOPT_CERTINFO` 172
- `CURLOPT_PASSWORD` 10174
- `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR` 161
- `CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD` 10176
- `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME` 10175
- `CURLOPT_USERNAME` 10173
- `CURLOPT_NOPROXY` 10177
- `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS` 181
- `CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS` 182
- `CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC` 180
- `CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE` 10179
- `CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE` 178
- `CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS` 10183
- `CURLOPT_FTP_USE_PRET` 188
- `CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM` 10186
- `CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT` 10187
- `CURLOPT_RTSP_CLIENT_CSEQ` 193
- `CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST` 189
- `CURLOPT_RTSP_SERVER_CSEQ` 194
- `CURLOPT_RTSP_SESSION_ID` 10190
- `CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI` 10191
- `CURLOPT_RTSP_TRANSPORT` 10192
- `CURLOPT_FNMATCH_FUNCTION` 20200
- `CURLOPT_WILDCARDMATCH` 197
- `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` 10203
- `CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_PASSWORD` 10205
- `CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_TYPE` 10206
- `CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_USERNAME` 10204
- `CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING` 10102
- `CURLOPT_TRANSFER_ENCODING` 207
- `CURLOPT_GSSAPI_DELEGATION` 210
- `CURLOPT_ACCEPTTIMEOUT_MS` 212
- `CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS` 10211
- `CURLOPT_MAIL_AUTH` 10217
- `CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS` 216
- `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE` 213
- `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE` 214
- `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL` 215
- `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` -1

Comment: I don't think these are the actual option values. Each of those options is a constant which is internally represented as an integer. Looking at the values you've listed, I think those are just those internal integers.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly the same the other answer does (where the author states in a comment that it doesn't answer the question).