# How to get an option previously set with curl_setopt()?

Tags: php, curl

I'm just wondering as there is no curl_getopt() function, how it is possible to find out which value has been set for a specific option with [`curl_setopt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) previously?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Pulled from various answers around the internets:

> **Question:** Is there a way to get the
>   current curl option settings? Like a
>   curl_getopt() or curl_showopts()?
>
> **Answer:** Yes and no. There is
>   [curl_getinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) which will show you some
>   info about  the last connection, but I
>   suspect it's not what you're looking
>   for. It's a weakness in curl, IMHO.

My suggestion (and others) is to encapsulate cURL into a class where your `$cURL->setOpt()` function also stores the value for retrieval later.

The [multirequest](https://github.com/barbushin/multirequest) PHP library has this functionality (and then some!):

```php
$request = new \MultiRequest\Request($url);
$request->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
// ...
$curlOptions = $request->getCurlOptions();
list($proxyIp, $proxyPort) = explode(':', $curlOptions[CURLOPT_PROXY]);
```

Comment: Yes I'm actually missing that function, I've checked cUrl itself and it doesn't provide it as well. I assume that if the libcurl integrates this, PHP will follow on.

Answer (score 12):

Possibly `curl_getinfo()` may satisfy some of your needs.
If not, you can write a wrapper of `curl_setopt()` which saves all options to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // in C version of libcurl
    CURLcode code;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl){
        // Set CURL option
        code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, 
                                CURLOPT_URL,    
                                "https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL.html");
        // Get CURL option
        char *request_url = NULL;
        code = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &request_url);
        if (CURLE_OK == code && request_url){
            printf("URL: %s", request_url);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
```