# Is it possible to use shared hosting IP as a proxy?

Tags: proxy, cpanel, ip-address, shared-hosting, proxies

Is it possible to use my shared hosting IP as a proxy? I have cPanel access to my hosting, and I need a proxy to use in a software. Is it possible and how? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use self hosted open source script https://www.glype.com/ It will provide feature you proxy site.

and if you want to use curl with proxy than try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618663/2384642

Comment: Thanks! But this works only for web browsing? I'd like to use a proxy in a software, where I need to add IP, user / pass, port ... anyway to do this? Thanks again.

Comment: No, in shared hosting its not possible, if you need own proxy server then you will need a root access server than you can install any open source proxy system.