# Can I call curl_setopt with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER multiple times to set multiple headers?

Tags: php, curl

Can I call [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` multiple times to set multiple headers?

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/';

$curlHandle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: gfhjui'));

$execResult = curl_exec($curlHandle);
```

Comment: Why would you call a function multiple times when you can do this only once and get the same result? You're justing giving more overhead and you might mud the code with header declarations all over the place.

Comment: It could have be useful to set some parameters conditionnally or if you create a default curl handle in a procedure and add specific headers later.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Following what curl does internally for the request (via the method outlined in [this answer to *"Php - Debugging Curl"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/367456)) answers the question: **No**.

No, it is not possible to use [`curl_setopt(PHP)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` more than once, passing it a single header each time, in order to set multiple headers.

A second call will overwrite the headers of a previous call (e.g. of the first call).

Instead the function needs to be called once with all headers:

```
$headers = [
    'Content-type: application/xml',
    'Authorization: gfhjui',
];
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Related (but different) questions are:

- [How to send a header using a HTTP request through a curl call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call) (curl on the commandline)
- [How to get an option previously set with curl_setopt()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5356075/367456) (curl PHP extension)

Answer (score 19):

Other type of format :

```
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-length: 0';

curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * If $header is an array of headers
 * It will format and return the correct $header
 * $header = [
 *  'Accept' => 'application/json',
 *  'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 * ];
 */
$header; //**
if (is_array($header)) {
    $i_header = $header;
    $header = [];
    foreach ($i_header as $param => $value) {
        $header[] = "$param: $value";
    }
}
```