# PHP: adding values into an existing key in HTTP header

Tags: java, php, curl

There is a function called `URLConnection addRequestProperty(String key, String value)` in Java, which could add values into an existing key, like `conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", requestMap.get("responseCookie"))`
How can I implement this function in PHP? I'm using the cURL, which has `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers)`, but it will delete the original values stored in the key. How can I append values into a key? Or I need to implement another class? Thanks!

Comment: You had better show us some actual code

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can show you the logic, cause I don't write any PHP code yet. Every time a request comes into the server, we read the cookie. If a cookie key called "Cookie" exist, we need to keep its key, and add value called "responseCookie" from a third-party interface; if not, we create the cookie "Cookie" and store the "responseCookie" into the key. Now my job is to convert the Java code into PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curl functions do not manage that for you (see as well [Can I call curl_setopt with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER multiple times to set multiple headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15134575/367456)), so you would need to implement that your own and/or use an existing library that is curl based which has such a functionality.

Comment: So that means I need to read the values stored in the key first, and add the new one into the values and put them back to the key?

Comment: If you want to handle it your own, you need to do the bookkeeping of set headers so that you can add more later on.

Comment: Fortunately, I know all the keys to be updated, and they won't be too many. Thanks a lot!