# how to pass token parameter in GET request in php curl?

Tags: php, access-token, php-curl

In my Laravel 5.8 app, I use API with method description :

```
curl --location --request GET "/api/user" \
   --header "Accept: application/json" \
   --header "Authorization: Bearer <user access token>"
```

But I failed how to pass token parameter in GET request in php curl?

I tried to do

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->serverApiHosting . '/api/user');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"));

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

$respArray = json_decode($resp);
```

I received the message:

> Redirecting to http://myserver.com/login.

Similar problem with url :

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->admindashApi . '/api/user?token=' . $logged_user_token);
```

I tried like :

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->admindashApi . '/api/user?Authorization=' . 'Bearer '. $logged_user_token);
```

But got error :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at phpstack-NNN-NNNN.cloudwaysapps.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
</pre>
```

Do I have to put it in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`?
How can I do this?
Which is the valid way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I call curl\_setopt with CURLOPT\_HTTPHEADER multiple times to set multiple headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134575/can-i-call-curl-setopt-with-curlopt-httpheader-multiple-times-to-set-multiple-he)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you have to add your header to `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

This can be done by adding to the PHP array object you're setting to `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

```php
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$logged_user_token
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Here, you will be creating the php Array object `$headers` with *both* the `Authorization` and `Content-Type` headers. You then set your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to use that array of headers.