# Set global CURL timeout

Tags: php, curl

I am using a proprietary, 3rd party Drupal module that queries a 3rd party service via curl.  The service has been a bit flakey lately, which is slowing my page loads a lot and when I've got a lot of traffic I am hitting max_connections.

The information that this extension queries is not vital, but it is important enough that I can't just remove the module.  For the time being, I fixed it by patching the module to add a curl timeout to the request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
```

However, I don't want to leave the hack in place because it'll disappear on the next update and since the problem is intermittent it won't show up in testing.

Is there any way to set the timeout globally in a php.ini setting or in PHP via code (that I could drop in a custom module)?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's `default_socket_timeout`, default is 60 seconds

Comment: @PKeidel that solved it for me.  Please write an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PHP's CURL uses the php.ini setting `default_socket_timeout`. The default value is 60, the unit is seconds.

Comment: AFAIK this is NOT true: "cURL has an indefinite timeout by default and does not obey the default_socket_timeout INI setting. This means that you have to configure the timeout in every cURL call in your code." https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/using-http-client-timeouts-in-php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php In the table the default value for "default_socket_timeout" is shown as "60". So no need for a down vote

Comment: Curl does NOT honor that value

Comment: Where is that documented?

Comment: I updated this in my php.ini file and the cUrl timeout changed. Ignore @drAlberT 's comments

Comment: Maybe you could be right, but on what php version? Are you sure your test is valid on 8.x and 7.x?

Comment: @drAlberT I tried this answer on php 8 and it worked. curl changed its timeout.

Comment: Guys probably I got that behavior on an old PHP version .. I don't remember now. So, yep .. ignore the comment and go ahead ;)

Answer (score 2):

The author and maintainer states [here](https://curl.se/mail/lib-2003-05/0097.html):

> > When using libcurl, if CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT is not set, what is the
> > default timeout value in seconds?
>
> None at all.

A more complete answer can be found on [another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15982505/3756263):

> libcurl lists the following connection timeout specific settings:
>
> - CURLOPT_FTP_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT: No default (indefinite)
> - CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: No default (indefinite)
> - CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS: No default (indefinite)
> - CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT: Defaults to 300 seconds
> - CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS: No default
> - CURLOPT_ACCEPTTIMEOUT_MS: Defaults to 60000 ms
>
> The PHP source code does not override any of the above default settings: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/curl/interface.c. The only somewhat related parameter that the PHP bindings override is `CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT`, changing the default value from 60 seconds to 120 seconds: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a0e3ca1c986681d0136ce4550359ecee2826a80c/ext/curl/interface.c#L1926

So: No, php-curl does not honour the `default_socket_timeout` setting. We even found several servers stuck with day-old (or even multiple month-old) curl-requests when investigating some customer problems.

And it seems there is no way to set the timeout globally.