# How to set or circumvent CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT in PHP globally?

Tags: php, curl, timeout, php-7.2, php-ini

Is there a way to set the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` somehow globally for all cURL requests?

I have an issue where after an upgrade to PHP 7.2 some software’s cURLs now fail at a 10s connect timeout when before they did not. I can't exactly say what changed this behavior, but I need to somehow globally set either a) what causes this to now time out, or b) increase the timeout limit.

Any `php.ini` settings that can affect this?

Edit:
Setting `default_socket_timeout` does not seem to affect this.

Edit:
FYI same issue with more Wordpress specifics: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/330013/curl-28-error-after-switch-from-to-brew-php-7-2-on-localhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set global CURL timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602256/set-global-curl-timeout)

Comment: @A.JAlhorr 1) I am inquiring about `CONNECTTIMEOUT` not `TIMEOUT` and thus b) `CONNECTTIMEOUT` does not seem to respect that `php.ini` setting mentioned in that answer.

Comment: ye you're right. it takes 300 sec as a default value, but could't find where it gets that value from, probably the curl's dll. Well I found this on github, maybe it could help https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/652

Comment: @A.JAlhorr Thanks, but that solution seem to be application specific and only for that library (which probably in turn applies it to all cURL requests it makes)

Comment: The default 300 seconds is [hard-coded in the libcurl code](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/8754ddb85daf0d4eeae985b1ba954745b6f360fd/lib/connect.h#L43).

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT option and does it work when you do that? The reason I ask is because people are saying that the default is 300 seconds but you said that it times out after 10 seconds.

Comment: Why don't you use wrapper for curl function or auto_prepend_file?

Comment: @KodosJohnson The 10s is a default set in WordPress, but I don’t see any change in the codebase there that would have caused this. Somehow this change in behavior was triggered by my PHP update, or so it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any php.ini settings that can affect this?

don't think so.  if you have [PCEL Runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) installed and `runkit.internal_override=1` in php.ini, then you could add this to a `auto_prepend_file` php.ini file, which should make your own timeouts the global defaults:

```
<?php
runkit_function_rename('curl_init','curl_original_init');
runkit_function_add ( 'curl_init' , '$url=null','$ch=curl_original_init($url);curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>100,CURLOPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=>100));return $ch;');
```

- note that many people would consider this to be `an evil hack`, technically changing the behavior of php builtin functions n all..

Comment: I believe this is a viable work around. What appears to have caused this issue was a problem with my PC DNS settings that actually caused those connection timeouts. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/330409/27033