# PHRETS Works Locally But Times Out On Web Server

Tags: php, rets, phrets, mls

I installed PHRETS with Composer and have been able to print information using CMD terminal and following the docs. I tried uploading all the files to my web server, but the page times out.

My error log shows the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException' with message 'cURL error 7: Failed to connect to rets-rald.realtyserver.com port 6103: Connection timed out' in /public_html/phrets/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlFactory.php:126
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/phrets/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlFactory.php(91): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlFactory::createErrorResponse(Array, Array, Array)
#1 /public_html/phrets/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlHandler.php(96): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlFactory::createResponse(Array, Array, Array, Array, Resource id #69)
#2 /public_html/phrets/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlHandler.php(68): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlHandler->_invokeAsArray(Array)
#3 /public_html/phrets/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/Middleware.php(54): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlHandler->__invoke(Array)
#4 /public_html/phrets/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/Middlewa in /public_html/phrets/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 49
```

How can I get it working on the web server? Below is my configuration.

```
$config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
$config->setLoginUrl('http://rets-rald.realtyserver.com:6103/saskatchewan/rets/login');
$config->setUsername('username');
$config->setPassword('password');
$config->setRetsVersion('1.5');
$config->setUserAgent('PHRETS/2.0');
$config->setHttpAuthenticationMethod('digest');
$config->setOption('use_post_method', false);
$config->setOption('disable_follow_location', false);
```

Comment: PHRETS seems to be using Guzzle HTTP client which in turns uses cURL. cURL uses `default_socket_timeout` configuration parameter (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308915/php-default-curl-timeout-value), try comparing that parameter in your local and remote machines.

Comment: They're both 60. Any other suggestions? The data from the terminal comes back instantly. Seems strange that it would be timing out in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I just needed to enable port 6103 on the server.

Comment: I am having this exact problem. How did you enable the port? Is this still possible on a GoDaddy Shared Hosting account?