# UP-TO-DATE correct usage of multi cURL (curl_multi_select )?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, php-curl

After looking at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) examples and contributor codes, I found that there are different approaches, however some of them either doesn't work after testing or [are deprecated](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64443). 
Over internet [different articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20%20multi%20curl) suggest different approaches:

```
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh,$active); 
}  
while ($active > 0);
```

other examples/programmers used "advanced" way:

```
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) {
        usleep(1000);
    }
    else {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell, which is the up-to-date and best usage of `curl_multi_exec` ? 
(btw, personally me, [i've found](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/beaa6979998bf222310a2e2436b768771e514b8a) that `usleep` doenst make any performance )

Comment: what's actually going wrong with the code?

Comment: Why care about using cURL directly and not use some library like Guzzle?

Comment: What do you mean by "advantages of Guzzle"? IMO, it's always good to use libraries that abstract such questions, especially in terms of all these cURL options. But as I don't know much about `curl_multi_exec` and it's usage, I write this as a comment

Comment: @T.Todua from what I can see in the docs, it's not deprecated (yet, if it does) - but that's the same for all functions, unless there's an announcement to plan the deprecation of the function, I'd say it's still good to use :) but I could be wrong :p

Answer (score 1):

The `usleep()` call doesn't "improve performance". It is there to avoid a busy-loop for the case where the function doesn't wait on anything but return instantly. That can happen in particular for (some older) libcurl versions during the name resolver phase in the beginning of a transfer. (That precaution can be probably removed in the future when CURL/PHP won't behave like that anymore.)

But you can for sure skip the checks for `CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM` since libcurl hasn't returned that since very many years. So, that would make it just

```
$active = 1;
$mrc = CURLM_OK;
while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) {
        usleep(1000);
    }
    else {
       $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, even Daniel responded to the question... honor for me, thank you  ;)

Comment: I will probably just copy paste your provided code, without any extra questions.. just, 
i might ask a last thing -  with my initial example benchmark code, i have found finally, that without `usleep` it was faster... am i wrong?

Comment: No, that's probably not wrong. The problem with that approach is only when the state remains for an extended period of time as your program will use 100% CPU during it. And modern libcurl versions won't return -1 there so it should not happen with them...