# What is the actual value of CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION if it is set to 84? Does that correspond to CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0 or CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to find the value of the HTTP protocol that curl is using in a particular PHP application. I haven't been able to find a documented default for this.

Following a code snippet from [this useful stackoverflow post (default-curl-option-values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880238/default-curl-option-values) I was able to print out the values of the curl options just before doing the curl_exec.

The result was `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION = 84`. However the three constants that we can use to set this are:

```
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE = 0
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0 = 1
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 = 2
```

Therefore the question is: What does a value of 84 imply? I am not seeing how the above constants can translate to 84 in some kind of bit combination? I could try [this posted alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866946/how-can-i-see-the-request-headers-made-by-curl-when-sending-a-request-to-the-ser) way of seeing what curl is doing but I am still curious about how to read the option value.

Comment: `84` is probably an index or offset in an cURL-internal data structure. And the correct answer to "how do I read a cURL-internal variable/setting?" is "you don't.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CURL_HTTP_VERSION` isn't a variable you set, it's a parameter you supply to `curl_setopt()` to tell it which option you're setting. So `84` is just the number of this option, and its value is meaningless (except to the internals of `curl_setopt()`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was mixed up about the constants for the option names vs. their values. I was able to use the snippet in this post to see the whole request including the protocol: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4406238/1331768

Comment: Any ideas why after setting CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION to 3 (which means HTTP2) the request is still sent as HTTP/1.1? I have PHP 5.6.

Comment: @Andrew As far as I can tell, the only valid values of `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` are the values of the constants `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE`, `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0`, and `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1`. Where did you learn that you can set it to `3`?

Comment: The CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0 constant was added in libcurl 7.33: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION.html. Its internal value is 3, as I've seen in some examples around here.

Comment: But does PHP use that version of libcurl?